# Selenium won't open a new url in for loop (Python & Chrome)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I can't seem to get Selenium to run this for loop correctly. It runs the first time without issue but when it starts the second loop to the program just stops running with no error message. I get the same results when I attempt this with a firefox browser. Maybe it has to do with me trying to start a browser instance when one is already running?

```
def bookroom(self):
sessionrooms=["611", "618"] #the list being used by the for loop   
        driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
        #for loop trying each room
        for rooms in sessionrooms:
            room=roomoptions[rooms][0]
            sidenum=roomoptions[rooms][1]
            bookingurl="https://coparooms.newschool.edu/copa-scheduler/Web/reservation.php?rid="+room+"&sid="+sidenum+"&rd="+self.startdate
            driver.get(bookingurl)
            time.sleep(3)
            usernamefield = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
            usernamefield.send_keys(self.username)
            passwordfield = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
            passwordfield.send_keys(self.password)
            passwordfield.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
            time.sleep(5)
            begin=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("beginPeriod"))
            print(self.starttime)
            begin.select_by_visible_text(convertarmy(self.starttime))
            end=Select(driver.find_element_by_name("endPeriod"))
            end.select_by_visible_text(convertarmy(self.endtime))
creates=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Create')]")
            creates.click() #clicks the confirm button
            time.sleep(8)
            xpathtest=driver.find_element_by_id("result").text
            #if statement checks if creation was a success. If it is, exit the browser.
            if "success" in xpathtest or "Success" in xpathtest:
                print "Success!"
                driver.exit()
            else:
                print "Failure"
                time.sleep(2)
            #if creation was not success try the next room in sessionrooms
```

**Update:**

I found the problem, it was just a matter of uneven spacing. Only some of the loop was "in the loop".

Comment: Can you trim down your code to reproduce it? Maybe just a loop where it tries to redirect? I don't know that all this code would be relevant to the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

```
if "success" in xpathtest or "Success" in xpathtest:
    print "Success!"
    driver.exit()
```

You will want to break out of your loop here, as you're closing the driver, but using it in the next iteration of the loop without starting a new driver object

Comment: When I try to put a break in the if statement the console tells me I'm  using a break outside of the context of the loop